# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarLayout')

Tags: android

First let me tell you that I am new to site. Any issues regarding posting, please forgive. I used to find the solutions from this site solve the problems. But here I got stuck. I did search a lot and I tried to resolve it with the solutions provided but the issue still there. Please help me.

Here is the code

**Layout file**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.user.securedata.DataProtectionSelective">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
```

Comment: You dont have `AppTheme.AppBarLayout` in your styles. I guess you have to change it to `AppTheme.AppBarOverlay`

Comment: change <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" /> into <style name="AppTheme.AppBarLayout" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

Comment: I am sorry. I got the mistake I did. Please ignore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```